# How to catch keyboard layout change

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I have several issues:

- Catch keyboard layout change event.
- Get current keyboard language.
- Change keyboard layout from my program.

I tried this first:

```
bool MyWindow::event(QEvent* e)
{
    if (e->type() == QEvent::KeyboardLayoutChange)
        qDebug() << "Keyboard Layout Changed";

    return QWidget::event(e);
}
```

But this type of event is never passed. Also, I have no idea how to solve the other 2 issues.

Could you please show me any workable example on the latest Qt version or some other cross-platform solutions of this problem?

Qt 5.0.2 
Windows 7 Visual Studio 2012 
Ubuntu 12.04  G++ 4.7.0

Comment: This is a regression in Qt 5: https://bugreports.qt-project.org/browse/QTBUG-27681

Comment: @Mitch Thanks. I do not saw that report before.

Answer (score 1):

There is no cross-platform solution to get the keyboard language or to change its layout from within Qt. You'll need platform-specific solutions: one for Windows, one for X11. In the future you'd need Wayland as well, I'd presume.