# How to catch keyboard layout change under Linux

Tags: c++, linux, qt, qt5

Here is my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17346849/how-to-catch-keyboard-layout-change). I am trying to solve this problem with the platform-dependent code below. On Windows, all work fine. But on Linux, I can't get the language name, only the country. Also, I don't know what message (on Linux) is associated with the keyboard layout change event. I used [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3230761/how-to-change-keyboard-layout-a-x11-api-solution) for the Linux part.

```
bool MainWindow::nativeEvent(const QByteArray& eventType, void* message, long* result)
{
#ifdef Q_OS_WIN
    MSG* msg = reinterpret_cast<MSG*>(message);
    if(msg && msg->message == WM_INPUTLANGCHANGE)
    {
        HKL hkl_id = GetKeyboardLayout(0);
        int lang_id =  LOWORD(hkl_id);
        wchar_t buf[11] = {0};
        GetLocaleInfo( MAKELCID(lang_id, SORT_DEFAULT), 
                       LOCALE_SISO639LANGNAME, 
                       buf, 
                       10);
        qDebug() << QString::fromWCharArray(buf);  // "EN"
    }
#endif // Q_OS_WIN
#ifdef Q_OS_LINUX
    xcb_generic_event_t* ev = reinterpret_cast<xcb_generic_event_t *>(message);
    if(ev)
    {
        switch (ev->response_type & ~0x80)
        {
        case XCB_KEY_PRESS:
        {
            qDebug() << endl;
            XKeyboard xkb;
            qDebug() << QString::fromStdString(xkb.currentGroupSymbol());  // "US"
        }
        break;
        }
    }
#endif // Q_OS_LINUX
    return QMainWindow::nativeEvent(eventType, message, result);
}
```

Comment: Try `KeymapNotify` events.

Comment: Also `xkb_keymap_layout_get_name`.